# File iteration I/O C programming

Tags: c, file-io, while-loop, iteration

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     char line[100];


     f = fopen("test.text", "r+");
     while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f)) {
                    size_t len = strlen(line);
                    if (strlen(line)!=*argv[1]){
                    fputs("Oh noez Errorz\n", stderr);
            }
}
```

Hey guys, I'm reall confused I'm trying to check an argument to see if the same size as first line of characters in a textfile.

So if the textfile contained

'AA'

and the argument was given was infact '2'. Then it would be logically correct, and not throw an error.

Comment: Then you need to convert `argv[1]` to an integer. `*argv[1]` does **not** do that.

Comment: Better not to put NUL characters in text files.

Comment: I just declared, this:
int length = strlen(argv[1])
and replaced with if(strlen(line)!=length)

Comment: didnt seem to make much difference..

Comment: `if (strlen(line)!=*argv[1]){` --> `if (len != atoi(argv[1]))`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(argc >=2)
{
  int num = atoi(argv[1]);
  if(len != num)
    fputs("Oh noez Errorz\n", stderr);
}
```